# I can send data using body raw but not using formdata using post method in postman

Tags: php, api, postman, codeigniter-3

I am just trying to upload a profile picure with my update profile api. I can send data simply by body raw using json (post) method but for uploading  file i am using  formdata and in that i can't send any data. i get only response that please provide input details.

Here is my api controller code

```
 public function update_profile()
{
    $this->default_file();
    $responseData = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['u_id']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['u_id'];
        $userData['u_id'] = $id;
        $userData['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $userData['usermob'] = $_POST['usermob'];
        $userData['userlocation'] = $_POST['userlocation'];

        $update_profile = $this->apm->update_profile($userData);

        if(!empty($update_profile))
        {
            $id = $_POST['u_id'];
            $userDetails = array();
            $userDetails['id'] = $id;
            $getUserDetails = $this->apm->getUserDetails($userDetails);

            $responseData['u_id'] = $getUserDetails['result']['u_id'];
            $responseData['username'] = $getUserDetails['result']['username'];
            $responseData['useremail'] = $getUserDetails['result']['useremail'];
            $responseData['usermob'] = $getUserDetails['result']['usermob'];
            $responseData['userlocation'] = $getUserDetails['result']['userlocation'];

            $responseArray = array(
                'apiName' => 'update profile',
                'version' => '1.0.0',
                'responseCode' => 200,
                'responseMessage' => "Your profile updated successfully",
                'responseData' => $responseData
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $responseArray = array(
                'apiName' => 'update profile',
                'version' => '1.0.0',
                'responseCode' => 204,
                'responseMessage' => "error in updating profile",
                'responseData' => null//$responseData
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $responseArray = array(
            'apiName' => 'update profile',
            'version' => '1.0.0',
            'responseCode' => 204,
            'responseMessage' => "Sorry, please provide your input details.",
            'responseData' => null//$responseData
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($responseArray);
    die();
}
```

i am submitting the code without adding the image part code to check simple submit data using formdata.

Here is my api modal code

```
public function update_profile($userData)
{
    return $this->db->update('users', $userData, array('u_id' => $userData['u_id']));
}

public function getUserDetails($userDetails = array())
{
    $arrData = array();
    if($userDetails['id'])
    {
        $where = "u_id='". $userDetails['id']."'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        if(!empty($result))
        {
            $arrData['result'] = $result[0];
        }
        else
        {
            $arrData['result'] = '';
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
}
```

This is default file code

```
 function default_file(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type ");
    header("Content-Type:application/json ");
    $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $_POST = json_decode($rest_json,true);
}
```

Please help me in running my code using formdata so that i can upload a image through that api.

Answer (score 0):

FormData objects are not encoded as JSON (which is sensible since JSON doesn't support the File data type and the big benefit of FormData is that it does).

FormData objects will be encoded as `multipart/form-data` which will be automatically parsed by PHP and used to populate `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.

Unfortunately, your code (`$_POST = json_decode($rest_json,true);`) overwrites the data you want with the results to trying to parse, as JSON, something which isn't JSON.

NB: When using FormData, make sure you **don't** overwrite the `Content-Type` header on the request.

Comment: Done sir remove the line $this->default_file() and the code works fine.